# How can i change the type "free form text" from being case sensetive?

Tags: actions-on-google

I am trying to create a Quiz.
Answering by voice with an answer being A, B or C does work.
Now while trying to find out how my action recognizes the word or words that the users says, i have to realize that the assistant is always case sensitive.

Example: In my Quiz the answer is "Beautiful".
When the user says the word, it is recognized as "beautiful", so that the answer
will be incorrect as it is written with a small "b".

Is there a way to make the Action Console ignore case sensitivity ?

Comment: Can you change your quiz mechanics so that it can accept one or the other?

Comment: I haven't seen case sensitive matching behavior. Can you provide the code you're using or a screen shot that demonstrates how you're doing this and what you're seeing?